# How to update/reinitiate mmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I've tried using the jQuery.mmenu-plugin, found here http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/. It works great with pre-defined lists, but how do I handle lists which are updated with jQuery?

Here's an example of an initialized mmenu:

```
<nav id="menu" class="mm-menu mm-horizontal mm-ismenu mm-hasheader mm-hassearch mm-current mm-opened">
    <div class="mm-panel mm-opened mm-current" id="mm-m1-p0">               
       <ul id="list" class="mm-list">
            <li id="1"><a>item 1</a></li>
            <li id="2"><a>item 2</a></li>
            <li id="3"><a>item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Then I append items to the list the following way:

```
$("#list").append('<li id="4"><a>"item 4"</a></li>');
```

The appended (fourth) li-item won't get the same behavior as the li-items defined before initialize the mmenu. This means that items added after the initialization won't work with the search field, as an example.

Is there a way to reinitiate the mmenu or to update the li-items connected to it?

Comment: An `id` shouldn't be only a number or even starting by a number.

Comment: The list above is just an example, I'm not using it. But yeah, I shouldn't even have added any id to those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked through the Plugin's (`mmenu.js`) code briefly, you could alter the JavaScript to listen to the DOM for new `<a[href="#id"']>` elements:

Adjust:

```
  click( $('a[href="#' + id + '"]', that.$menu), function( e ) {
       $opening.trigger( evt );
  }
```

to:

```
  click( $(document).find('a[href="#' + id + '"]', that.$menu ), function( e ) {
       $opening.trigger( evt );
  }
```

This'll make sure that the `$menu` can be used for any Loaded & Non-Loaded DOM elements.

**Alternatively,** You could reinitialise it:

```
var $Mmenu = $('#menu'),
    $Container = $Mmenu.parent(),
    $List  = $('#menu #list');

    $List.append('<li id="4"><a>"item 4"</a></li>');

var newHtml = $Mmenu.html();

    $Mmenu.remove();
    $Container.append( newHtml );
    $(document).find('#menu').mmenu();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the answer doesn't seem to be enough for solving the problem.

List items that are added still won't get the mmenu-behaviour. Clicking an appended item won't set the class to "mm-selected".

Comment: Updated with alternative, I suppose there's more of the plugin code you would need to edit to make newly appended DOM elements to work.

Comment: @Gustav Also, there are three places that you need edit for the first suggestion to work, it's not only one line.

Comment: I went with an approach similar to your alternative solution. Even though removing and adding the menu doesn't make me feel that comfortable, it works. Thank you!

Comment: I agree it's not the most comfortable solution! Maybe submitting a ticket to the plugin author will probably construct a cleaner version of new dom elements, or I might fork a version myself when I get the chance :-)

Answer (score 1):

The instance of the plugin is attached to the menu.  The counter addon registers an update function on the plugin that is used by the search addon to affect changes in other plugins.  e.g. when you type into the search box, it will prune the visible children of the submenus and update the counter.

To wire into this you need the instance of the plugin that is attached to your menu element (because there is an array with the registered update functions)

So, if you have an element like this:

`<nav id="menu"></nav>`

that you initialized via:

```
$("#menu").mmenu();
```

then call the `_update()` method on the plugin object:

```
$("#menu").data('mmenu')._update();
    'menu' is the id of my menu element
    'mmenu' is the name of the plugin
    _update() is the magic function that will call all the update functions registered in the updates array
```

Comment: This is working fine, but there is a problem when attempt to dynamically add submenu and update. My submenu list is updated pretty good but there is no back button/link to the previous parent menu. Am I missing something @jkeane?